# Stop cursor from jumpping to end of input field

Tags: javascript, html, angular

i'm working on a Angular2 application. I'm trying to mask a creditcard. Everything is fine but I got an issue.

For example I enterd 2222-3333-1111. After that I realized I forgot to enter 0000 between 2 and 3. When I try to enter the value between 2 and 3, the cursor moving to end and the output is like "2222-0333-3111-1000".

I tried some solutions from stackOverFlow but nothing helped me. Please suggest me some solution to solve this.

Below is the code which I have implimented

```
protected digitPattern =  /\d{1,4}\-{0,1}\d{0,4}\-{0,1}\d{0,4}-{0,1}\d{0,4}-{0,1}\d{0,4}/;

constructor(model: FormControlName) {
  this.model = model;
}

@HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInput(event: any) {
  const currentValue = this.model.value;

  this.updateValue(currentValue);
}

@HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event']) onNgModelChange(currentValue: string) {
  this.updateValue(currentValue);
}

// updates the actual and displayed values
updateValue(currentValue: string) {
  const actualValue = this.getActualValue(currentValue);
  const maskedValue = this.getMaskedValue(actualValue);

  if (currentValue !== actualValue) {
    // This is the actual binding (unmasked) value
    this.model.control.setValue(actualValue, {emitModelToViewChange: false});
  }

  // This is the displaying (masked) value
  this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(maskedValue);
}

// Returns the masked value
getMaskedValue(actualValue: string): string {
  let maskedValue = '';

  const unmaskedValue = actualValue.replace(/\D+/g, '');

for (let i = 0; i < unmaskedValue.length && i < 23; i++) {
  if (!(i % 4) && (i > 0)) {
      maskedValue += this.separator;
    }
    maskedValue += unmaskedValue[i];
  }


 if (actualValue.endsWith(this.separator)) {
    if (maskedValue.length === 3 || maskedValue.length === 7) {
      maskedValue += this.separator;
    }
  }

  return maskedValue;
}

// Returns the actual (unmasked) value
getActualValue(currentValue: string): string {
  let result = '';

  // Check if something is available to mask
  if (currentValue && currentValue.length > 0) {
    const digits = currentValue.match(this.digitPattern);

    if (digits) {
      for (const value of digits) {
        result += value;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I would say that you are updating on keystrokes, and when you do it updates the textbox jumping the carret to the end of the input.

Comment: Thanks @Edgar , so you are saying keystorkes creating the problem here ? if so then whats the solution would you prefer to fix this

Comment: If I am correct, and I don't know if I am. I would save on leaving the input.